# Parse a string to save the data on mongo db

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, hash, mongoid

I have a .txt file which contains no of insert query like this. I want to parse the file.txt and get the data in order to save in my mongoid db for my rails application.i tried parsing using basic ruby methods but unable to get the proper format. Can i obtain a hash from the data which can directly be used to implement bulk insert or regex to parse and get the values only.

```
INSERT INTO "venues" ("_id", "postal_code", "lat", "lng", "address", "title", "type") 
VALUES (33, "SW1A 0AA", "51.49984", "-0.124663", "BIG BEN & HOUSES OF PARLIAMENT, House of 
Commons, London, SW1A 0AA","BIG BEN & HOUSES OF PARLIAMENT", 2);
```

Comment: suggested by my friend and it works item.scan(/VALUES\s\(.+\)/).first.gsub(/VALUES\s\(|\)|\"/,"").split(", ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item.scan(/VALUES\s(.+)/).first.gsub(/VALUES\s(|)|\"/,"").split(", ")

Answer (score 1):

You need an regexp that takes a `INSERT INTO (...)` and `VALUES (...)` parts and doesn't depends from new lines symbols. For example:

```
str.gsub(/(\r|\n)/, '') =~ /INSERT INTO "(\w{1,})" \((.*{1,})\) VALUES \((.*{1,})\)/
```

Then you will have next variables:

```
table, keys, values = $1, $2, $3
```

You also can clean keys and values from extra symbols:

```
keys.split(",").map {|val| val.gsub("\"", '').strip }
values.split(",").map {|val| val.gsub("\"", '').strip }
```

So now you have all needed data to process migration to MongoDB.